# Can't read in image web2py

Tags: python, web2py

Hello I'm having problems opening a image file in web2py. I don't know if I'm making just a simple mistake or that it'd more than that. I thought I was doing it right looking at examples from the web and on this site. Heres my code in the model:

```
db.define_table('image', 
                 Field('picture', 'upload'))
```

I think the error means that there is a picture in the database but it can't retrieve that image and open it or I be completely wrong please if anyone can spread some light on the solution i will be very thankful

Comment: What is `Image.open()`? Note, `db.image.picture` is just a DAL Field object -- it is not an image or a file.

Comment: open is a function in the image module class. so db.image.picture is a DAL field object and not a image. so how can i put a image in the database then open that specific image thats in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter passed to `Image.open`, `db.image.picture`, is a `Field` object and not the value that was filled into the form. You probably want:

```
pic = Image.open(os.path.join(request.folder,'uploads',form.vars.picture))
```

Edit: Updated to use full path to the picture file. However, as pointed out by Anthony in comments below, this will not work with a `blob` field that was used to store the image in the original question (before it was edited as discussed in comments below). The use of `retrieve` as described [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#More-on-uploads) will provide the file data.

Comment: thank you sir for trying to help when I did what you suggested it gave me this error <type 'exceptions.IOError'> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image.picture.b40612132e08cda1.54756c6970732e6a7067.jpg' Now i think it doesnt know where the picture is

Comment: @CalvinJones The files themselves are in the `uploads` folder of the application. Please see [this](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#SQLFORM-and-uploads) documentation. So you will have to add the path to the uploads folder before the filename. I have updated my answer. Could you please try the updated line?

Comment: No, the file is not on the file system in the uploads folder in this case because a blob field was specified to store the files in the database instead.

Comment: well i can take the blob part out to make it easier

Comment: @Anthony Good observation. I guess OP will need to use [`retrieve`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#More-on-uploads) to get the file data. OP, please try without the `blob` and see if that works for you.

Comment: ok right now i'm testing it out i took out blob and seeing if it works give me a minute to see please and thank you so much for your help

Comment: Excellent. When you get it working, could you please remove the `uploadfield` part of the `picture` field definition in your question so it reads `Field('picture', 'upload')`.  :D

Comment: it's taking a long time actually but no errors showing up so maybe it works and and made edit

Comment: Are you doing anything else with the `pic` variable? The above code will simply open (and subsequently close) the image file. It will not display it or do anything else with it.

Comment: i think its just my PC because my web2py application keep freezing lol if i get the same error ill make sure to contact you thanks again for your help god bless you and your family